# put(s) and take(s) in BlockingQueue Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, blockingqueue

Here is the example.

```
class Factory {
    Queue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();

    public Object consume() {
        queue.take();
    }

    public void produce() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            queue.put(new Object());
        }
    }
}
```

For example I have two threads which both called consume(). They are waiting for a producer to put something in the queue. My question is whether after a put() action a take() action happens, or is it possible for two put() actions to happen one after the other and only after that the waiting threads will return ?

Thank you.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` is an `interface`. In any case; don't assume any order when it comes to threads. Most likely the `take()` will happen after the `put()` - but it might happen that the tread woken by the `put()` might be beaten to the punch by the other other `put()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as put finishes, lock is released now lets assume put and take both are waiting on that lock again and its unfair lock then any of the methods Put/Take can get hold of lock and start. 
**There is no ordered and alternate exchange of monitor(lock) unless specified.**

See the code by java.

[ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java)

[ReentrantLock](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#ReentrantLock)

[AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#AbstractQueuedSynchronizer)